# Displaying a toast without window

Tags: android, android-activity, toast

My application is unusual: when it starts up, it simply displays a Toast message.
That is, I have to click on the launch icon, see Toast and that's it.
But after launching, I am less than a second, I see the main application window, which should not be shown at all - only Toast! It is displayed and immediately closed.
I use

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(this, "This is my Toast message!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
}
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: app without activity - is it possible? What I need to write in manifest in intent-filter  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely a very strange app.

Although you can launch a `Toast` from anywhere you have access to a `Context`, you definitely need to use an `Activity` due to the need for supplying a Launcher Icon on the homescreen.

However, by default, even if a layout isn't created or 'set', the Activity's window will still show. This is the typical behavior because the behavior has it's own elements and a Layout is simply added inside of this default Activity window.

But this doesn't mean you can't do what you want.

You simply have to make that Activity window not be shown. This is most commonly done through styles.

To do this, you can use this theme:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Simply add that theme to your Activity inside your 'Manifest.xml'

There are other translucent themes you can try if you don't want to use the FullScreen No Title Bar version.

Answer (score 1):

You said you didn't want to use a translucent Activity, but that seems to be the best way to do this:

1. In your Manifest, set the Activity theme to `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`.

   ```
   <application
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
       ...
       ...>
   ```
2. Don't bother with a layout for your Activity, and don't call `setContentView()`.
3. In your Activity's `onCreate()`, **Show your Toast** now.
4. Exit the Activity with `finish()`.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       finish();
   }
   ```

In other words, your Activity doesn't have to be visible; **Just Toast will be display.**

Answer (score -1):

```
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout));
            TextView text = layout.findViewById(R.id.tv_custom_toast);
            text.setText("You have not marked any favourites");
            Toast toast = new Toast(this);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 50);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.show();
```

Create a custom toast.. Here Custom_toast_layout have textview background should be transparent ..